# Convert image URL to image tag within the anchor tag

Tags: php, regex

I want to convert url of image`(jpg,jpeg,png,gif)` within the anchor tag to html image tag with that image url.

Eg:

Convert

`<a href="http://google.com/image.jpg">http://google.com/image.jpg</a>`

to

`<a href="http://google.com/image.jpg"><img src="http://google.com/image.jpg" /></a>`

Please help me with any regex expression to check and convert.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want using native PHP function [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) like this:

```
<?php

$anchor = '<a href="http://google.com/image.jpg">http://google.com/image.jpg</a>';
echo $imageInsideAnchor = preg_replace('|>(.+)<|', '><img src="${1}"><', $anchor);
```

Note: In above code, `${1}` represents image URL captured by regex: `|>(.+)<|`.